# Adding a pause to service restart

Tags: c#

I am a little less new to programming than I was a week ago, I had some great help on getting a problem point I was stuck on taken care of. I am hoping for some luck this go around as well. I created a form with a button that backups SQL databases, I wanted to add a start and stop to the MSSQLSERVER service, and I believe I have this working properly. The only thing is it flashes on the screen so fast I can not confirm (I know more for my peace of mind than anything) if it actually stops and starts. Here is my code so far:

```
private void Backup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string root = @"C:\Tools";
         // If directory does not exist, create it. 
        if (!Directory.Exists(root))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(root);
        }

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();

        con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source= localhost; Initial Catalog= Local;Integrated Security=True;";

        string database = con.Database.ToString();
        try
        {
           {
                string cmd = "BACKUP DATABASE [" + database + "] TO DISK='" + @"C:\Tools" + "\\" + "Local" + "-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd--HH-mm-ss") + ".bak'";

                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(cmd, con))
                {
                    if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                    {
                        con.Open();
                    }
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show("database backup done successefully");
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("net", "stop MSSQLSERVER").WaitForExit();
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("net", "start MSSQLSERVER").WaitForExit();
                }
            }

        }
        catch
        {

        }
     }
```

I appreciate any and all help.

I just wanted to add this worked for me in case anyone else ever needs it:

````
private void Backup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string root = @"C:\Tools";
             // If directory does not exist, create it. 
            if (!Directory.Exists(root))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(root);
            }

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();

            con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source= localhost; Initial Catalog= Local;Integrated Security=True;";

            string database = con.Database.ToString();
            try
            {
               {
                    string cmd = "BACKUP DATABASE [" + database + "] TO DISK='" + @"C:\Tools" + "\\" + "Local" + "-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd--HH-mm-ss") + ".bak'";

                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(cmd, con))
                    {
                        if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                        {
                            con.Open();
                        }
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        con.Close();
                        MessageBox.Show("database backup done successefully");
                        ServiceController service = new ServiceController("SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)");
                        service.Stop(); 
                        MessageBox.Show("SQL Server was stopped successfully");
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
                        service.Start();
                        MessageBox.Show("SQL Server was restarted successfully");
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"error occurred: {ex.ToString()}");
            }
                    }
    ```

Thanks for all the help.
````

Comment: Try adding breakpoints in the code, then check that SQL Server status when you hit them. Also, you could open a MessageBox after each step to notify that the server was stopped/started.

Comment: If you comment the line where you are starting again MSSQLSERVER, you'll know if your service is stopped by checking in services.msc

Comment: You can use [ServiceController](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller?view=netframework-4.8) to interact with services rather than having to launch other processes to ask them to do (small amounts) of work for you.

Comment: You should execute your application as administrator too

Comment: It can be nice too to handle the eventuals errors in the `catch`. You can get the error using `catch (Exception ex)` and then, a simple `MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);` can be a good start to know if an error has occured

Comment: @CoderLee I had already tried with the breakpoint, but had not thought to try the message box. Let me give that a try and see what it does

Comment: @Cid I completely forgot I could take the start out, I am going to try the message box and then this to make sure it stops and starts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try displaying messages to alert you, or the user, to the state of your application like below:

```
try
{
    {
        string cmd = "BACKUP DATABASE [" + database + "] TO DISK='" + @"C:\Tools" + "\\" + "Local" + "-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd--HH-mm-ss") + ".bak'";

        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(cmd, con))
        {
            if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                con.Open();
            }
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("database backup done successfully");
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("net", "stop MSSQLSERVER").WaitForExit();
            MessageBox.Show("SQL Server was stopped successfully");
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("net", "start MSSQLSERVER").WaitForExit();
            MessageBox.Show("SQL Server was restarted successfully");
        }
    }

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox($"error occurred: {ex.ToString()}");
}
```

You can catch can display errors in your catch() or alert for server started/stopped as each occurs. That way you won't have to guess what it is, but have a clear message to go off of.

If you want to stop/start a **Service** instead of the process then try using `System.ServiceProcess` eg:

```
 ServiceController service = new ServiceController("SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)");
 service.Stop();
 service.Start();
```

Keep in mind you'll want to run as and admin to get that to work.

Comment: I'm starting to think this

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("net", "stop MSSQLSERVER").WaitForExit();
```

Isnt doing what I thought it does, when I check my services after commenting out the start it still shows running. I may have to change how it handles the start and stop

Comment: That's stopping the process, so if you look at Task Manager you'll see the SQL Server NT 64 process stop and start. I updated my answer for Services in case that's what you wanted instead.

Comment: Thanks CoderLee, I was meaning the service not the process, I changed the code to reflect the service, which works great to stop it, but errors on start saying that it is already running, so now im thinking I may need to delay the start. But as they say slow and steady

Comment: Glad that worked for you! Hopefully anyone else with the same will find this post too.